# Is it possible to use multiple NIBs mixed in a UICollectionView?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, mvvmcross, nib

I have to create a view such as the iTunes Appstore with 3 different types of blocks: one for an image (ImageBlock), another for a list of object1 (Type1List) and a third for a list of object2 (Type2List).

I have functional MvxCollectionViewCells for all of the three, but I'd need to make an UICollectionView out of these three. I have an list of these lists (Items). A single list (Item) has a value called "type", which is an integer value 1, 2 or 3. I'd have to get this integer value for each Item and determine the NIB I want to use for this specific cell.

```
//Collection = UICollectionView
//ViewModel.Items = MvxObservableCollection<Item>

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<View, ViewModel>();

    // NIBs for types 1, 2 and 3 respectively
    Collection.RegisterNibForCell(Type1List.Nib, Type1List.Key);
    Collection.RegisterNibForCell(Type2List.Nib, Type2List.Key);
    Collection.RegisterNibForCell(ImageBlock.Nib, ImageBlock.Key);

    // This shows all items of type 1 correctly, and others using type 1 XIB with no contents
    Source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(Collection, Type1List.Key);

    // This gives a Null Reference Exception if used in place of the previous one
    //Source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(Collection);

    set.Bind(Source)
        .To(vm => vm.Items);

    // This takes the items and calculates the height for Collection in this View
    // All types will differ in size
    set.Bind(CollectionHeight)
        .For(v => v.Constant)
        .To(vm => vm.Items)
        .WithConversion("IosCollectionHeight", Collection);

    Collection.Source = Source;

    // Set to 200 for now to see the cells
    // TODO: set a working variable size
    (Collection.CollectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout).ItemSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 200);
    //(Collection.CollectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout).EstimatedItemSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 100);

    set.Apply();

    Collection.ReloadData();
}
```

So I have currently 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to use different NIBs by type for my UICollectionView
2. I don't know how to resize cells by type

All three cell NIBs are tested and working as intended, but this CollectionView is problematic.

-Pasketi

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin, but in iOS at least, it's the same way as using different Custom Classes for `UICollectionViewCell` or for `UITableViewCell`. The fact that it's with `registerNib:` or Storyboard, or `registerClass:` doesn't matter.

Comment: add cellforRowAtIndexpath method for collectionview

Comment: @Larme Creating a custom CollectionViewSource gave me the effect I wanted, as now my CollectionView has 3 different XIB's in their respective places. Huzzah! However all the content has vanished and the cells are just empty husks, containing nothing more than the labels I've set to them.

Long story short, the MvvmCross binding never happens.